# Порекомендуйте книгу по языку программирования Си

Tags: c, книги, информация

Можете порекомендовать книги по языку программирования Си (НЕ начинающий уровень), желательно с примерами. Те вопросы, которые я нашел, заданы более 6-7 лет назад, вот и думал может что-нибудь новое вышло

Comment: Ну, последние несколько лет вообще кризис жанра, стало выходить куда меньше компьютерной литературы. Та же "Диалектика" полностью переориентировалась на психологическую. Плюс С — язык не столь востребованный, как другие, да и гораздо более стабильный, в нем каждый год новая версия не выходит, да и каждые три года тоже... Так что смело пользуйтесь найденными вами книгами...

Comment: Камран Амини - Экстремальный Си

Comment: [Практика программирования. Керниган Б., Пайк Р.](https://www.moscowbooks.ru/book/989768/)

Comment: [Modern C. Jens Gustedt](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-02383654/document).